# un-sort results in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am stuck with `FIND_IN_SET` function in MYSQL 5.5, For example:

Please check below query, considering `10,9,5,8,21` are user id's

```
SELECT u.user_id,u.first_name,u.last_name
FROM user u 
WHERE 
u.is_active = 'Y'       
AND FIND_IN_SET(u.user_id,'10,9,5,8,21');
```

When I fire this query it give me results in Ascending order of user id's that is in

```
5
8
9
10
21
```

I want in same order like I entered

```
10
9
5
8
21
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

STORED PROCEDURE

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS databaseName.procName;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE databaseName.procName(IN ZoneIDs LONGTEXT)

BEGIN       
        SELECT u.user_id,u.first_name,u.last_name

        FROM user u     
        WHERE u.is_active = 'Y'
        AND FIND_IN_SET(u.user_id,ZoneIDs); 

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Never seen `find_in_set` used in a where clause before ?!?! it just returns the index of the first argument within the second argument ... your not comparing it with anything ?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using it like this :

```
SELECT u.user_id,u.first_name,u.last_name
FROM user u 
WHERE u.is_active = 'Y' and u.user_id IN (10,9,5,8,21)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(u.user_id,'10,9,5,8,21');
```

This uses `IN` to only select data where `u.userid` is in that list and then orders by your specific order using `find_in_set`

[FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) returns the index of the first argument in the second argument - so I'm very surprised your query even worked .....

Comment: ManseUK Thanks for your response, simple doubt, How can i pass (10,9,5,8,21) values dynamically in "u.user_id IN (10,9,5,8,21)"
where as ('10,9,5,8,21') is varchar in "FIND_IN_SET(u.user_id,'10,9,5,8,21')", please help

Comment: @RajneelJoshi are the values stored in an array ? can you include the PHP in your question that you use to create this query ?

Comment: I am using this query in stored procedure

Comment: @RajneelJoshi and how do you pass the values to the stored procedure at the moment ?

Comment: i had posted my stored procedure in my question please check it